# How to use JUnit for testing classes in Android app without using Android?

Tags: android, junit, junit4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't run JUnit 4 test case in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172152/cant-run-junit-4-test-case-in-eclipse)

I have an Android application, which contains plain Java class. I want to test this class without using Android device or Emulator, but when I create JUnit 4 test suite and case & run int (as JUnit test in Eclipse), it says the following:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=5492, tid=5608
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
```

What should I do?

Comment: Similar to [Can't run JUnit 4 test case in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172152/cant-run-junit-4-test-case-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 3):

If you want unit tests to run locally, you need to run your tests from a **Java** project (as opposed to an Android project). I think the reason you get that error is because you're running Dalvik bytecode on the JVM.

You can separate your java code into a java library that you unit test.

Or you can use [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/index.html) to test your code as is. Robolectric rewrites Android SDK classes so you can run them locally. The [Eclipse quickstart](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html) is useful for getting started. You'll be creating a java junit project and not an Android test project.

An alternate approach to Robolectric is to use mock frameworks such as [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or [Android Mock](http://code.google.com/p/android-mock/) to mock out the Android SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to separate the "plain Java code" into an own library which can be tested independently from you android application. The solution is also recommended [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-using.html#android-dev-sect-multimodule) (Maven: The Complete Reference).

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522312/best-practices-for-unit-testing-android-apps) has some good information on unit testing on Android. And a link to Robolectric which might be an alternative you're looking for.

Comment: I **don't** want to use Android device or emulator to test **plain** Java classes.

Comment: @RankoR I suggest you to read the whole thread. There are some good ideas there for any thought you have :) For example you could dig this link https://sites.google.com/site/androiddevtesting/

Comment: Robolectric (which Dennis mentioned in his answer) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to use the [AndroidTestRunner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestRunner.html) and the [AndroidTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html) for JUnit on Android.

Comment: it's not exactly "running test cases without using android". this way the test cases will be run on emulator/device

Comment: I don't want to use android to test this classes - I want to run this tests on my local machine.