# No class def found error for JUnit Test on android

Tags: android, junit

I am having some very bizarre behaviour. I have a large number of test cases for my Android application, and they all work except for one. When I run this one I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.JUnit.test

Yes, I have the JUnit 4 library imported into the project, and my other JUnit tests are running without any problems. What is particularly bizarre is that before I hit this problem I had an error in my code- basically, I tried writing a file to a read only folder. When that occurred, the JUnitTest would execute up to the point where it would hit an IO exception for accessing a part of memory it cannot access. I fix this problem, and suddenly the Android emulator doesn't seem to know what org.JUnit.test is.

I have examined the run configuration for this test class, and it is the same as my others.  It is in the same folder as the other tests as well. It also uses the same import statements. Any idea on what is going on?

I am using the Android 10 emulator, and eclipse version 3.7.2.

Edit: To clarify, the error I get appears on Logcat and not in my Eclipse project.

Comment: JUnit4 was *(is? haven't tested in a while)* problematic with android, use JUnit3 instead if you can. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788953/android-junit4-testing). Also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2172175/658042), it might help you to fix the problem *(didn't test that either)*.

Comment: Ugh. Well, I was trying to port over a java project over to Android, and the tests were built around JUnit4. Replacing this with JUnit3 gives a whole bunch of compiler exceptions, but I suppose I could try and get through all of those. It seems just bizarre and arbitrary that this fails on just ONE of my test cases though.