# JUnit3 with a common setUp() for multiple tests

Tags: android, sql, junit3

How can I group a few tests that have a common dependency, so that `setUp()`/`tearDown()` is executed for the whole group? I want to test SQL queries execution times but not including the time to load the database at each test `setUp()`! `TestSuite` doesn't even have `setUp()` method! I just want to load the database before the first test and then perform each query in a separate test and then close and delete it after all tests are done. Can I have a common context/scope shared between tests or test methods?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if JUnit3 has this (I would assume so, it's kind of important!), but in JUnit 4 there is an @Before and @After tag used for con/de-struction. [some before docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) and [some after docs](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html)

Comment: I know but Android supports only JUnit3. And I don't want to use 3rd party solutions for JUnit4 support.

Comment: I didn't know that. I did find something on SO that might help though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11916340/480691

Comment: Seems the thing I'm trying to do is not just a test but more of a benchmark. As I see JUnit3 is designed so that all tests run as new instances, not sharing any state. Maybe I have to try a more complex testing solution.